# Create/Edit leads from Customer community profile users

Tags: community, permissions, leads, customer-community

I have some Customer Community Profile user who would like to create leads.

From what I understand Customer Community Profile users do not have CRED permissions to create leads and we can't provide access.

I would like to understand if there is any work around.

Answer (score 1):

There are no workaround for Customer Community Profile user to access leads.

Here is the License type and functionality mapping.

[image: License type]

You need to upgrade to Partner Community License.